# Redirecting to not-found page after reloading page (localize-router localization)

Tags: angular, routes

Im using localize-router module for localization, after first intilization the routing localization working fine (http://localhost:4200/en) after reload it redirecting to not found page here is my app-rounting

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: './com/wedoapps/views/main/main.module#MainModule',
    data: {
      metafrenzy: {
        title: '',
        tags: [
          {
            name: 'og:title',
            content: ''
          }, {
            name: 'og:description',
            content: ''
          }, {
            name: 'og:image',
            content: ''
          }
        ],
        links: [
          {
            rel: 'canonical',
            href: 'http://localhost/'
          }
        ]
      }
    }},
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**If no Control over server where ui is deployed.**

RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});

**If have control over server where ui is deployed**

do setting of returning index.html in case of not found url.

Comment: if you don't have control over backend and can't change backend configuration. this is the only way.

Comment: still added other way as well.